# iPad Interface Orientation Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

When user tap on the UIView (which is fullscreen) my app needs to detect orientation and do some stuff. But there is one tiny problem.
If I start application in landscape mode and user tap background 'interfaceOrientation' variable is '0' and I don't know how to rearrange view elements. If I rotate simulator once everything is fine but if not 'interfaceOrientation' is '0'. What to do here?

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {        
       ...            
    }  
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {       
        ...
    }
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
...
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `[super viewDidLoad]` from your view controller's `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Yes I call it, but it's still '0'

Comment: What happens if you add a call to `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]` in your `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how well that is solvable. UIDeviceOrientationUnknown is 0. This means, especially for the iPad which hasn't got a gyroscope, that the orientation at this time is simply not know. Imagine your iPad laying on a table, flat and the user is starting your application: there isn't any means to define that your application is actually running in landscape or portrait, unless you tilt the device accordingly. Hence.. the orientation at startup is always 0 (unknown).

Comment: It seams that this is the real problem. Orientation is unknown if app is started and device isn't rotated. Grrr... anybody have some solution for this?

Comment: So if application is started on table it will not have orientation set so I did next. If the orientation is unknown I set view elements position and if user does'n like he must rotate device. Stupid solution but I don't see another way.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting a `UIDeviceOrientation` type to a `UIInterfaceOrientation` type. Device orientations have several different values beyond those of an interface orientation.

Try using:

```
 UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

switch (deviceOrientation) {
    default:
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
    case UIDeviceOrientationUnknown:
        //...
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        //...
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        //...
        break;
}
```

Edit: If the device orientation is unknown you should just set up your regular portrait view.

Comment: When I do that I get: UIDeviceOrientationUnknown

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` if you can't access `self.interfaceOrientation` from your view controller.

Also, sometimes calling `self.interfaceOrientation` in `viewDidLoad` is risky because the view will load before it is aware of its orientation, so it will perform the rotation afterwards. In that case try finding it in `viewWillAppear`.

Or just override `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration` and pass that information to the UIView that needs it. Note: that won't get called if you have a xib set to that orientation.